# Setting the constraints of a views subviews without knowing the amount of subviews there are

Tags: xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

So my view is pretty simple to setup but I can't figure out how to do a specific task.

So what I need to do is take in an array of strings, each one of these strings are a country ISO3 format code which in turn have a corresponding flag associated with it. Now after I add the flags to the view I need to be able to set all the constraints.

So first I add the imagesviews to the view, that works fine but now when I get to the `updateConstraints` method I am unsure how to proceed since I have an unknown amount of subviews.

So each subview will be placed about 5 spaces apart from the flag before it and the top of the image and bottom of the image should span the views height.

How can I write code that handles an arbitrary number of subviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So first i add the imagesviews to the view

As you do that, also add each view's constraints. Since you are looping through the flags / image views, you *know* whether there was a previous image view and if you've taken a little care, you have a reference to it. Thus, there is actually *not* a lot of code — it's a loop, and not a very long one — and it isn't at all difficult.

As an alternative, I suppose you could use a UIStackView (if you are not running on iOS 8). It will just take all the image views and space them out with constraints for you; all *you* have to do is decide on its size, which you can presumably do by counting the image views.

Comment: I guess im over thinking this then. I mean i get exactly what you are saying but is there any other way to do this other than checking the previous index?

Comment: Here's an actual example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p362scrollViewInCode2/ch20p670scrollViewInCode2/ViewController.swift The successive views happen to be labels, not image views, but the fundamental principle, and thus the overall structure of the code, is exactly the same as the sort of thing you want to do.

Comment: And another thing is I thought we had to use the ```updateConstraints``` method to do all my autolayout code. I thought that was the case because by the time the ```updateConstraints``` method is called the superviews constrains should be adding the the stack

Comment: The code I pointed you to is correct and works. What you thought is sort of outside my metaphysical sphere of competence. :)

Comment: and no i cant use a stackview because its not an iOS 9.0 project its an 8.0 and above

Comment: Yeah, that's why I put that caveat in.

Comment: Ive been using autolayout for a while now and have a good understanding of it i just need to find out a bunch of little tips and tricks that come along with programming autolayout views

Comment: Actually to think about it what i just read is that theres a method called ```appendContentsOf`` which is apart of the NSLAyoutConstraint class, that might be what im looking for ill update you in a minute

Comment: I just completed it and my original thoughts were right and it wasnt as much code as i thought. The github post you posted is the correct way to go about it.